# @Value not resolving the placeholder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I am using springboot 2.6.9, I am trying to find it hard to find the root cause of this problem.

```
 @Bean
ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations(
        @Value("${set.token-uri}") String token_uri,
        @Value("${set.client-id}") String client_id,
        @Value("${set.client-secret}") String client_secret,
        @Value("${set.scope}") String scope,
        @Value("${set.authorization-grant-type}") String authorizationGrantType

)
```

application.properties

```
set.token-uri=https://myapp.aut.otken/token
```

These properties are present in my application. properties, but my application still fails to start because it is unable to resolve the placeholder. This is an issue I'm having with Intellij and command line. I tried going through all of the issues related to this, but I can't figure out why. Is there an open bug in this version of spring boot, or is something else causing this problem? For my build, I'm using Gradle. I attempted to clear the Gradle cache and Intellij cache, tried upgrading the gradle version.

```
      @Slf4j
      @Service
      @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "app.rabbitmq", name = "enabled",havingValue = "true")
   public class RabbitMQListener {
    @Autowired
    private MyManagementService myManagementService 

    @RabbitListener(queues = {"${rabbitmq.queue.name}"})
    public void consume(String message) {
        log.info("Received Message on my channel :{}", message);
        if(!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
            MessageRequest messageRequest = (MessageRequest) JSONUtils.convertStringToObject(message, MessageRequest.class);
            myManagementService.uploadToServer(Long.parseLong(messageRequest.getRequestedId()));
            
        }
    }
```

}

When I explicitly add the propertySource, the problem is resolved; I'm not sure why this is necessary. I'm not sure if this will affect the configuration server. Could you please tell me what the problem is? I looked through the build folder but couldn't find the application.properties file. Because spring configuration uses AMQP, will adding the RabbitMQ properties cause this issue? I see if the RabbitMQ is enabled the start up is proper. The issue is happening only when the RabbitMQ is not available. I tried adding conditional on RabbitMQ bean but still issue persists.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

Answer (score 0):

I replicated this issue in my local. Nothing to do with the SpringBoot version. This is an IntelliJ IDEA caching issue. Please perform these steps and try again.

File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is not specific to intellij. It is happening with commandline as well. I tried above mentioned steps does not help.

Comment: Ohh ok can you please share your project folder structure.

Comment: It is the standard one generated out of spring.io, this was working and suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Ok earlier it was working with spring boot 2.6.9 only?

Comment: Yes, it was working

Comment: That's strange, have you done any code changes recently?